# AWS EMR 5.11.0 - Apache Hive on Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, amazon-emr

I am trying to setup Apache Hive on Spark on AWS EMR 5.11.0. 
Apache Spark Version - 2.2.1
Apache Hive Version - 2.3.2
Yarn logs show below error:

18/01/28 21:55:28 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SPARK_RPC_SERVER_ADDRESS
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SPARK_RPC_SERVER_ADDRESS
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.rpc.RpcConfiguration.(RpcConfiguration.java:47)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver.(RemoteDriver.java:134)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver.main(RemoteDriver.java:516)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:635)

hive-server2.log:
2018-01-28T21:56:50,109 ERROR [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-68([])]: client.SparkClientImpl (SparkClientImpl.java:(112)) - Timed out waiting for client to connect.
Possible reasons include network issues, errors in remote driver or the cluster has no available resources, etc.
Please check YARN or Spark driver's logs for further information.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for client connection.
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:41) ~[netty-all-4.0.52.Final.jar:4.0.52.Final]
        at org.apache.hive.spark.client.SparkClientImpl.(SparkClientImpl.java:109) ~[hive-exec-2.3.2-amzn-0.jar:2.3.2-amzn-0]
        at org.apache.hive.spark.client.SparkClientFactory.createClient(SparkClientFactory.java:80) ~[hive-exec-2.3.2-amzn-0.jar:2.3.2-amzn-0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.RemoteHiveSparkClient.createRemoteClient(RemoteHiveSparkClient.java:101) ~[hive-exec-2.3.2-amzn-0.jar:2.3.2-amzn-0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.RemoteHiveSparkClient.(RemoteHiveSparkClient.java:97) ~[hive-exec-2.3.2-amzn-0.jar:2.3.2-amzn-0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.HiveSparkClientFactory.createHiveSparkClient(HiveSparkClientFactory.java:73) ~[hive-exec-2.3.2-amzn-0.jar:2.3.2-amzn-0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.session.SparkSessionImpl.open(SparkSessionImpl.java:62) ~[hive-exec-2.3.2-amzn-0.jar:2.3.2-amzn-0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.session.SparkSessionManagerImpl.getSession(SparkSessionManagerImpl.java:115) ~[hive-exec-2.3.2-amzn-0.jar:2.3.2-amzn-0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkUtilities.getSparkSession(SparkUtilities.java:126) ~[hive-exec-2.3.2-amzn-0.jar:2.3.2-amzn-0]

Also,
2018-01-28T21:56:50,110 ERROR [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-68([])]: spark.SparkTask (SessionState.java:printError(1126)) - Failed to execute spark task, with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException(Failed to create spark client.)'
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Failed to create spark client.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.session.SparkSessionImpl.open(SparkSessionImpl.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.session.SparkSessionManagerImpl.getSession(SparkSessionManagerImpl.java:115)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkUtilities.getSparkSession(SparkUtilities.java:126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask.execute(SparkTask.java:103)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1839)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1526)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1232)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:255)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$800(SQLOperation.java:91)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork$1.run(SQLOperation.java:348)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork.run(SQLOperation.java:362)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for client connection.

Could anyone point out what I maybe missing in the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but Hive on Spark is not yet supported on EMR. I have not tried it myself yet, but I think the likely cause of your errors might be a mismatch between the version of Spark supported on EMR and the version of Spark upon which Hive depends. The last time I checked, Hive did not support Spark 2.x when running Hive on Spark. Given that your first error is a NoSuchFieldError, it seems like a version mismatch is the most likely cause. The timeout error may be a red herring.

Comment: Hive wiki actually says Since Hive 2.2.0, Hive on Spark runs with Spark 2.0.0 and above.   https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started.

Comment: Oh, OK, thanks for letting me know! I should have confirmed before I said that, but I was just responding via my phone.

Comment: Hive 2.3.2's pom.xml  specifies spark version 2.0.0 and not 2.2.1. Maybe there is compatibility issue. I will dig more into this.

Answer (score 0):

EMR Spark supports Hive version 1.2.1 and not the hive 2.x version. Could you please check the hive jar versions available in **/usr/lib/spark/jars/** directory. SPARK_RPC_SERVER_ADDRESS is added in hive version 2.x.

Comment: Yes, the versions for hive jars is 1.2.1. Thanks for pointing out. So is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Please don't bundle the spark, hive related jars in your fat jar.  The scope of the jars to be provided.

Answer (score 0):

The sbt or pom.xml to be like as follows.

> "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % "provided",
>
> "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided",
>
> "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion % "provided",

I am running DataWarehouse (Hive) on EMR and spark application stored the data into DWH.

Comment: where is the sbt or pom.xml on emr master node ?

Answer (score 0):

I be able run hive on spark by run it like:

```
HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=$(find /usr/lib/spark/jars/ -name '*.jar' -and -not -name '*slf4j-log4j12*' -printf '%p:' | head -c-1) hive
```

Then, before other SQL queries issue:

```
SET hive.execution.engine = spark;
```

## To make that persistent

Add line

```
export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=$(find /usr/lib/spark/jars/ -name '*.jar' -and -not -name '*slf4j-log4j12*' -printf '%p:' | head -c-1)
```

into `/home/hadoop/.bashrc`

And in file `/etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml` set:

```xml
<property>
  <name>hive.execution.engine</name>
  <value>spark</value>
</property>
```